# How to update Blazor PWA on Visual Studio compilation?

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a Blazor PWA application and everytime i make any change to the pages and compile the project i have to clear the cache on the browser to see the changes. Should't the Visual Studio update the pages for us? After all if we are working in a project we are making changes to it and those should be reflected automatically upon pressing "run".
Is there any trick to force visual studio to show the updated content when compiling and running the application?

Comment: Did you use the standard template for a PWA Blazor app? Because that has two versions of the service worker file - one for local dev and one for release/publication - the local dev version does not cache.

Comment: Yes, i use the standard template. I don't know what do you mean with two versions. Do you mean service-worker.js and service-worker-published.js? I tryed to coment this last one as someone sugested to another person on stackoverflow and it didn't worked. When i compile and run i still need to clean cache to see the difference on edited files... It doesn't happens to you?

Comment: your `service-worker.js` should contain only: `self.addEventListener('fetch', () => { });`. does it? Also, did you try `dotnet watch run`?

Comment: You may have another service-worker registered against the localhost port you are running this project on. You could try changing port (launchsettings.json) or clearing the service-worker from your browser - in chromium browsers that's in dev  tools under Application/Storage/Clear Site data